# SQL Server shared resources: Login failed for user 'xxx'. Reason: The account is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've bought a SQL Server 2019 with a database as a service, **DBaaS**.
The provider has given me one account that is able to access R&W, to one database only, mine. Obviously, as I'm using a shared service, I can't access the master database.

I'm able to successfully connect with SQL Server Management Studio, by setting in the "connection properties" tab the "connect to database" value in order to not let access the master DB. I'm also able to connect to the database from an ASP.NET Core application using Entity Framework.

The application I'm using is an old ASP.NET 4.8 website, which uses the `DefaultMembershipProvider` to authenticate users.

The issue is exactly here as I've discovered that the error response

> Login failed for user 'xXxXxX'. Reason: The account is disabled.
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'xXxXxX'. Reason: The account is disabled.]
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +353
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +118   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +268
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +315   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +128
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +265   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +133   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +97
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +592   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.CheckDatabaseExists(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, String databaseName) +112
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbDatabaseExists(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +283
> System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.DatabaseExists() +118
> System.Web.Providers.Entities.DatabaseCreationHelper.DatabaseExists(ObjectContext context) +65
> System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +212

is caused by the method

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
```

which tries to connect to the `master` database and check if the database exists.

Obviously this is not allowed in a shared resource environment.

How can I disable this non-sense check on the `DefaultMembershipProvider`?

**Additional information**

The `web.config` section for the `MemberShipProvider` is defined like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="30" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="2" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="120">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

And the connection string is

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=123.123.123.123;Initial Catalog=MyOwnDatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=xXxXxX;Password=yyyZZZ;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: The master database password is created when the Server is installed.  You need that password or need to uninstall the database and reinstall.

Comment: @jdweng I ask for the master database password (maybe you mean the sa pwd) to DBaaS provider??? Like AWS or Azure, are you serious?!

Comment: I had issue a couple of years ago where an admin installed SQL Server and then I did not have permissions.  A few Admin tried to fix issue and couldn't.  They finally gave me local admin rights.  I finally uninstalled SQL Server and then reinstalled to get permissions correct.

Comment: @jdweng but that was still on-premises, right? OP is having issues with a cloud based db. I really doubt they will give the master pw.

Comment: @Fildor : My issue was I couldn't change the permissions of the database to allow users to connect.  Without the master password I didn't have the permissions necessary to make the changes.

Comment: The legacy [System.Web.Providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers) was intended for use with SQL Express, SQL Compact and (local) on-prem SQL Server installations. Have you tried porting to [Microsoft.AspNet.Providers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers) which also supports Azure SQL? In theory it might also work with hosted databases where you don't have access to the master database.

Comment: Why is it "Action`1 act" (near "UsingMasterConnection")?